# NSManagedObject [User setUsername:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have an app that uses CoreData.  I created NSManagedObjects for the two object types in CoreData. When I try to use the object and set a property on the object the compiler says "[User setUsername:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".  It doesn't matter what attribute I, [User setValue], try it always gives unrecognized?

```
User *joeBlow = [[User alloc] init];
[joeBlow setUsername:@"joeblow"];
```

OR 
    User *joeBlow = [[User alloc] init];
    joeBlow.username = @"JoeBlow";

both give "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Below is my code for USER:

User.h

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject

  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address1;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * username;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * zip;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;

@end
```

User.m

```
@implementation User

  @dynamic address1;
  @dynamic username;
  @dynamic zip;
  @dynamic email;

@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create new instances of Core Data entities by the normal `alloc`-`init` pattern (unlike other classes). Instead, call a class method on NSEntityDescription:

```
User *joeBlow = [NSEntityDescription 
                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User"
                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[joeBlow setUsername:@"joeblow"];
```

See Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html) for more information.

Finally, note that `[jb setUsername:@"jb"]` and `jb.username = @"jb"` are the same - the latter is *dot notation*, a different way of expressing the former.

Answer (score 0):

This correct answer is not true anymore. See here.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

```
Article *article = [Article new];
article.title = @"Introduction to RestKit";
article.body = @"This is some text.";
article.author = @"Blake";

// POST to create
[manager postObject:article path:@"/articles" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```